# Steam Connection Dialog

Tags: steam, technical-issues

A period of time after I've logged onto my computer a (minimisable) steam dialogue box appears telling me I am not connected;

[image: this one].

I first press "Quit". This dismisses the dialog window (and displays a smaller non-interactive one saying "quitting"). But then opens the steam browser in offline mode anyway*.

That's the problem, I don't expect steam to open in off-line mode when, ignoring the "open in offline mode" button, I press quit.

Known issue? Fixes?

I have: API : v012    ;  Package version: 1361807486/1361807486

<sup>*(by open I mean it appears in the task bar and notifications bar automatically maximises and gives focus to the steam browser).</sup>

Comment: This seems like a very steam specific question, but I believe it falls under "Game-specific hardware and utilities" and so is in scope.

Comment: Steam most certainly is on-topic here, no worries. :)  I'm not sure what, exactly, you're asking, though.

Comment: Are you online when the popup occurs? I get that when I'm not online and steam starts.

Comment: Yes, I am online. Steam doesn't ever recognise that I'm online (how ever many times I exit and restart it) until I ask it to "Go online". You might even say that's a bigger issue, but at least that issue doesn't make a fuss when I'm trying to do other things.

Comment: I can confirm this. I had router problems a while ago with this window popping up almost every time I started Steam. I think this is a bug in Steam, someone should tell them.

Comment: The strange thing is tho, when I do it, it does indeed open the steam browser but then it closed down.

Comment: I've got the same problem...glad it's not just me.

Comment: I think this bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand from your question you have issues connecting to steam? 
In this case, exit steam, delete clientregistry.blob from your steam folder and then restart the application, it should re-check and update what is necessary. If this is not working you should try to delete everything in the steam folder except the steamapps folder and steam.exe and restart your application.

Answer (score -2):

To fix this, download [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx)

Then Open TCPView with Administrator rights.

Then Run steam.exe, and when you see the steam.exe in Yellow/Red color inside TCPView.

Right click on it > CLOSE CONNECTION.

Do this very 10secs for 3 times. It will solve your problem.
(With TCPView, you are not closing application. you are closing connection. Once you close the connection steam chooses next closest server to initiate.)

Comment: Could you explain why this works?

Comment: When u close the connection, it try the another server from steam. Which eventually connects you to steam.

Comment: So you're saying that you have to do this every time Steam starts? Isn't that *more* complicated than just letting it start and then using its own Exit menu?

Comment: no. WHat i mean was, whn u close the connection. Steam chooses next server. And it helps steam to connect to server. you are not closing application, but you are closing connection.

Comment: Do you have to do this every time Steam runs, or will this make Steam "stick" with a better server that doesn't cause problems?

Comment: With TCPView, you are not closing application. you are closing connection. Once you close the connection steam chooses next closest server to initiate.